# asusctl and dkms-hid-asus-rog missing from repository?

Tags: asus, 21.04

This directory disappeared in the last few days:
https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/luke_nukem:/asus/xUbuntu_21.04

Where can I find asusctl and dkms-hid-asus-rog to install in Ubuntu? I'm using an ASUS Zephyrus G14.  Please forgive me if I ask this in the wrong place. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- find a way to contact original [repository](https://build.opensuse.org/repositories/home:luke_nukem:asus/asusctl) owner for example on their GitLab - https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl/-/issues/149 and temporary comment out the relevant line in `sources.list` (or use Software & Updates GUI application) and wait for solution;
- if you are in hurry - compile the application from [sources](https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl) by yourself using below procedure:

  ```
  sudo apt autopurge asusctl dkms-hid-asus-rog # remove debs first

  sudo apt install build-essential cargo git pkg-config libclang-dev libudev-dev

  cd ~/Downloads
  git clone https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/asusctl.git -b 4.0.6
  cd asusctl
  make
  sudo make install

  sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl restart asusd
  ```

  When all things will return to normal - uninstall self compiled version by

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads/asusctl
  sudo make uninstall
  sudo mv /etc/asusd ~/
  ```

  then reinstall deb-package when it will be available again.

---

Note: [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/hid-asus-rog-dkms-git) and [original repository owner](https://gitlab.com/asus-linux/hid-asus-rog) say that dkms-hid-asus-rog (hid-asus-rog-dkms) is now out of date and archived.